# Explaining S suffix to non-native English speaker

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english

I am assisting a Hebrew speaker in improving her skills in English.  She is having a difficult time understanding how English speakers use the S, and I am looking for the simplest way to explain this.  For example, the following phrases seem inconsistent to her: *It **sounds** right.* VS. *It doesn't **sound** right.*  If you can help me help her, it would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to teach her about verb conjugation.  It works slightly differently in English than in Hebrew, since English verbs aren't conjugated according to gender, and because the present tense has (in theory) different conjugations for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd person.  You'll also have to teach her about auxiliary, or "helper" verbs, which aren't present in Hebrew, and which explain the difference between "It sounds" and "It does sound" (or "it did sound")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely easy: **the s or es** is only ever in the **third person singular** of a verb in the present tense, except the verb be.

Third person is: It/He/She.

Structure of types of sentences:

Declarative: It **sounds** right.
Negative: It **does** not sound right. [doesn't]
Interrogative: **Does** it sound right?

It follows the rule except you have to know how to **form a question with the helping verb** ***do***. ***Do*** in the third person is ***does.*** There's your es.

Please note: there are other verbs that take ES in the third person in the declarative form: to slouch, slouches//to mooch, mooches//to finish, finishes etc.

Most though just take an s.

That is basically the only rule about any change to the verb form. English does not have "conjugations" except the one I just gave. It's call a third-person morpheme. Often, learners will forget "Does[subject or pronoun] [verb] and that is a bad mistake.

What is important, however, is the structure of the negative and interrogative. Also, once you learn that the structure of other tenses follows the same pattern of inversion with the helping verb (do).